# Writing metadata in c# on bitmap image and reading it on android eclipse?

Tags: c#, android, metadata

I have a bitmap image in c# and I am sending it to android via TCP.
Now I have to send some metadata with this image.I am getting help for both c# and android but separate.
Android mostly use EXIF like things for metadata and i read in one of the stackoverflow answer that android doesn't save metadata for bitmap images,I want to know that is it really so?
If yes or no how could I write something on the meta data of an image in c#.net and read that metadata on android??

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass information from an android system to any other system via any protocol e.g TCP, UDP, RTP or whatever) you need to do the following steps:

**First Method:**
1) Put information in image as hidden text (Not as metadata) using watermarking algorithms (Just google them...)

2) When you get image in other system (e.g .NET) use that system libraries to get those data back via same algorithm yo previously used for watermarking.

**Second Method :**
1) Just Send information as System information along with image but be sure that you are not sending any data with is not supported on reciever system. (e.g Telnet in windows does't allow some system informations from android system) You may have to bypass them through firewall as well.

> Do one of these steps and please let me know if that is helpful